# How to make Scaffold content (but not Bottom Bar) move up when keyboard is shown?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, padding, scaffold

I have scaffold content with `verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Bottom`.

How can I make the content move upwards when the keyboard is shown, but keep the bottom bar of the scaffold in place?

Answer (score 1):

I coded a full minimal example to familiarize myself with the mechanics, and since I had trouble finding good information myself, I thought I might as well post the code here to maybe help others.

Starting with an empty project (`File -> New -> New project -> Empty Activity`) in Android Studio, just add the line `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"` to the `<activity>` block of `AndroidManifest.xml` and then replace the content of `MainActivity.kt` with the code below.

Note the added `enableEdgeToEdge()` in `onCreate` which might be easy to overlook.

[image: Screenshot]

```
package com.example.test

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.activity.enableEdgeToEdge
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.ExperimentalLayoutApi
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.consumeWindowInsets
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.imePadding
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.material3.BottomAppBar
import androidx.compose.material3.ExperimentalMaterial3Api
import androidx.compose.material3.Scaffold
import androidx.compose.material3.TextField
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    @OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class, ExperimentalLayoutApi::class)
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        enableEdgeToEdge()
        setContent {
            Scaffold(
                containerColor = Color.Black,
                content = { innerPadding ->
                    Column(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxSize()
                            .padding(innerPadding)
                            .consumeWindowInsets(innerPadding)
                            .imePadding(),
                        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Bottom
                    ) {
                        TextField(
                            modifier = Modifier.padding(4.dp),
                            value = "Cat",
                            onValueChange = {}
                        )
                    }
                },
                bottomBar = { BottomAppBar {} }
            )
        }
    }
}
```